# ¿Como puedo obtener todos los resultados de una consulta SQL con jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, sql

Estoy realizando una consulta enviando datos concatenados pero solo me consulta el primero, seguí la documentación de php, pero me genera error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\etb\model\consulta_fibra.php on line 821

[image: ERROR]

if (isset($_POST['con_estmas']) ) {

```
    $con_estmas=$_POST['con_estmas'];
    


    $stid = oci_parse($conex, "select status_cd estado,ROW_ID pedido
                                from SIEBEL.S_ORDER@dblk_fo
                                    where ROW_ID in (:con_estmas
                                    ) AND STATUS_CD='Completada'");
        

        $ba = array(':con_estmas' => 1700); 
        foreach ($ba as $clave => $valor) {


                oci_bind_by_name($stid, $clave, $ba[$clave]);
            }                     
    

    oci_execute($stid);
    print '<table class="table table-bordered">';
            print '<thead>';
            print '<tr>';
            print '<th>ROW ID</th>';
            print '<th>Name</th>';
            print '</tr>';
            print '</thead>';
    $filas = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);

        foreach ($filas as $items) {
                print $items."<br>\n";
                }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Esto parece una confusión heredada del ejemplo del Manual de PHP:

```
$ba = array(':con_estmas' => 1700); 
foreach ($ba as $clave => $valor) {
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, $clave, $ba[$clave]);
}
```

Supongo que el parámetro real es `$con_estmas`. No tiene sentido hacer el `bind` dentro de un `for` cuando es un solo parámetro, lo puedes hacer directamente (ver **Ejemplo 4 del Manual**).

Intenta este código, con un control total de todos los posibles errores.

```
if (isset($_POST['con_estmas']) ) {
    if ($conex) {       
        $con_estmas=$_POST['con_estmas'];
    
        if ($stid = oci_parse($conex, "select status_cd estado,ROW_ID pedido
                                    from SIEBEL.S_ORDER@dblk_fo
                                        where ROW_ID in (:con_estmas
                                        ) AND STATUS_CD='Completada'")) 
        {
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':con_estmas', $con_estmas);
            if (oci_execute($stid) && $filas = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        
                $outPut="<table class=\"table table-bordered\">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>ROW ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>";
            
                foreach ($filas as $items) {
                    $outPut.="<tr><td>$items[estado]</td><td>$items[pedido]</td></tr>";
                }
                $outPut.="</table>";
            } else {
                #Sólo para depurar, conviene luego cambiar los mensajes de $e por mensajes personalizados
                $e = oci_error($conex);
                $outPut="Error ejecutando la consulta: ".htmlentities($e['message']);               
            }
        } else {
            #Sólo para depurar, conviene luego cambiar los mensajes de $e por mensajes personalizados
            $e = oci_error($conex);
            $outPut="Error preparando la consulta: ".htmlentities($e['message']);               
        }
    }else{
        $outPut="No hay conexión";
    }
} else {
    $outPut="No hay datos en el POST";
}
echo $outPut;
```

Comment: Hola, 
Muchas gracias por la respuesta...
Aunq que si lo ejecuto como dices me sigue presentando el mismo error
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\etb\model\consulta_fibra.php on line 811

Comment: ¿@DavidAlvarado podrías decirme lo que hay en la línea `811`? De paso, haz un test de los datos con  `var_dump($filas);` y dime lo que muestra.

Comment: Line 811foreach ($filas as $items) {
        print $items."<br>\n";
    }
}
El var_dum me genera : bool(false)

Comment: Entonces tu consulta no está trayendo datos. Conviene siempre controlar los errores y los resultados nulos antes de mostrar los eventuales resultados.

Comment: @DavidAlvarado revisa el nuevo código, con un control de todos los posibles errores.